# Glaring Spotlight anti-hexproof work on enchantments

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Does the [Glaring Spotlight](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Glaring%20Spotlight)'s anti-hexproof work on enchantments? So if a creature is not hexproof but has an enchantment such as [Alpha Authority](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Alpha%20Authority), does it still cancel the hexproof?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Glaring Spotlight affects hexproof from all sources, regardless of their type or the timestamp order of their effects.**

In many cases in Magic, when two continuous effects do opposite things, [we must look at their "timestamps" to figure out the final result](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/a/5979/).

Glaring Spotlight, however, doesn't *remove* hexproof from anything; what it does do is change *the rules* for hexproof. This modification applies to all instances of hexproof on creatures your opponents control, including hexproof granted by enchantments and artifacts.

From the Oracle rulings for [Glaring Spotlight](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bGlaring%20Spotlight%5d):

> Creatures your opponents control don’t actually lose hexproof, although you will ignore hexproof for purposes of choosing targets of spells and abilities you control.

Comment: Only until Wizards releases "Target creature can no longer be the target of spells and abilities your opponents control, even if other effects have made that creature targetable" or some other crazy hullabaloo...

Comment: Well, Glaring Spotlight refers to hexproof specifically. If a creature would be untargetable for some other reason (e.g. it has shroud), that other reason would continue to apply and would not be affected by Glaring Spotlight.